# StackExchange.Redis Really Slow with Hashes = C# ASP.NET Core 3.0 and Docker

Tags: c#, docker, redis

I am currently working on a web api that has to be fast and efficient when storing and sending data.  First, I tried `Entity Framework Core`, then `ADO.NET`, which significantly increased speed.

In order to leverage more speed, I tried setting up Redis.  However, I am shocked in terms of how slow it it is in comparison to `ADO.NET`.  Specifically, `ADO.NET` `541ms` and `Redis` up to `2.5s` to retrieve `32` objects with `5` properties via postman!

Here are some of the things I have done to optimize Redis:

- Made all my `HashGet` async
- Turned off persistent storage (though this was off anyway)
- Set `save` in `config` to `""`
- Created one global instance of `IDatabase` so just one connection is being used
- Created all my hashes at startup (see `RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.Hashes`)

My actual hashes (`RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.Hashes`) that represent each row of data start from `device1:input1` to `device32:input12`, a total of `384`.

Here is my partial CRUD class:

```
namespace StateAPI.RedisContext
{
    public class RedisCRUD : IRedisCRUD
    {
        // ^^^ store and re-use this!!!
        IDatabase db = RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.ConnectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

        public async Task<IEnumerable<StateRedis>> AllStatesAsync()
        {
            List<StateRedis> returnedDevices = new List<StateRedis>();

            foreach (string h in RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.Hashes)
            {
                StateRedis state = new StateRedis
                {
                    Id = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "id"),
                    InputState = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "state"),
                    OnPhrase = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "onphrase"),
                    OffPhrase = await db.HashGetAsync(h,"offphrase"),
                    When = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "when")
                };

                returnedDevices.Add(state);
            }

            return returnedDevices;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller for my api:

```
    // GET api/getallstates
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getallstates")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StateRedis>> GetAllStates()
    {
        return await _redisCRUD.AllStatesAsync(); // DI injected in
    }
```

Here is my StateRedis Model:

```
namespace StateAPI.Models
{
    public class StateRedis
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string InputState { get; set; }
        public string OnPhrase { get; set; }
        public string OffPhrase { get; set; }
        public string When { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is a Redis container for Docker and is running internally on a linux server running Docker.  SQL Server is also running from the same Docker server, and in general the server runs all our containers very well.  Mind you, I read on here that when someone's web project was in the same location as `Redis`, their problems went away?

The timings seem to fluctuate between `1` sec and `2.5` sec, so there is obviously a major bottle neck somewhere.

**Update**

My Redis connection helper:

```
namespace StateAPI.Helpers
{
    public class RedisConnectionHelper
    {
        private static RedisConnectionHelper _instance = null;

        public ConnectionMultiplexer ConnectionMultiplexer { get; set; }

        public List<string> Hashes { get; set;}

        public static RedisConnectionHelper Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null) _instance = new RedisConnectionHelper();
                return _instance;
            }
            protected set
            {
                _instance = value;
            }
        }

        public RedisConnectionHelper()
        {
            // ^^^ store and re-use this!!!
            ConnectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("dell-docker"); // Note that ConnectionMultiplexer implements IDisposable and can be disposed when no longer required

            // create hashes for each device and input e.g. device1:input12
            Hashes = new List<string>();

            int deviceCount = 1;
            int inputCount = 1;

            int numOfInputs = 12;
            int numOfDevices = 32;

            for (int i = 0; i < (numOfDevices * numOfInputs); i++)
            {
                if (i % numOfInputs == 0 && i != 0)
                {
                    inputCount = 1;
                    deviceCount = deviceCount + 1;
                }

                string deviceHash = $"device{deviceCount}:input{inputCount}";

                inputCount = inputCount + 1;

                Hashes.Add(deviceHash);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Created one global instance of `IDatabase` so just one connection is being used"_ FWIW the documentation says to store and reuse the `ConnectionMultiplexer`, not the `IDatabase` it returns.

Comment: Hashes are meant to accelerate lookups, not iterations. Iterations are *meant* to be slower, and your code makes one request per item, ie 384 roundtrips. What does your ORM/ADO.NET code look like? If it selects everything, the equivalent structure in Redis would be a list with all 384 items. On the other hand, 384 items is no data at all, so an indexed database table could easily stay cached in the server's memory (possibly in a single core's CPU cache) for a long time

Comment: you can use script (https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysValues) to get all the keys you need in a one shot. Would limit the connection and will be faster.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've updated my post, can you confirm I am storing and reusing the `ConnectionMultiplexer` correctly?  @Panagiotis, yes ADO.NET it will be selecting everything at once using `SqlDataReader` with Store Procedure.  @LeBigCat, will have a read of the link.  Still I would of thought even out the box with not the best efficient code, Redis would blitz SQL.

Comment: An update: I decided to run the Redis container locally as opposed to communicating with the Linux server, and I have got the time down to around `200ms` without any code tweaks.  I'm wondering if Redis needs to be running from the same server; however, an API call for the same data from the Linux server only takes `35ms` so I imagine I'm not out the woods yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The problem

The code you've posted is making 1920 round-trips to Redis (384 items in the `Hashes` collection x 5 requests each), and it's making them sequentially:

```
foreach (string h in RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.Hashes)
{
    StateRedis state = new StateRedis
    {
        Id = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "id"),              // Execution stops until Redis returns
        InputState = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "state"),   // Execution stops until Redis returns
        OnPhrase = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "onphrase"),  // Execution stops until Redis returns
        OffPhrase = await db.HashGetAsync(h,"offphrase"), // Execution stops until Redis returns
        When = await db.HashGetAsync(h, "when")           // Execution stops until Redis returns
    };

    returnedDevices.Add(state);
}
```

For each hash, this code is making 5 requests, *and waiting for each to return before making the next request*. Even if the latency to Redis is only 1ms, that would be 1920ms just waiting to receive the first byte from each response.

(Using async/await here does not help this problem. Although the thread is unblocked to serve *other* incoming requests, the `await` means that each call to `db.HashGetAsync()` does not begin until the previous one completes.)

This would be similar to making 1920 SQL queries like this:

```
SELECT id        FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 1
SELECT state     FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 1
SELECT onphrase  FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 1
SELECT offphrase FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 1
SELECT when      FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 1

SELECT id        FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 2
SELECT state     FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 2
SELECT onphrase  FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 2
SELECT offphrase FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 2
SELECT when      FROM data WHERE deviceID = 1 AND inputID = 2
...

SELECT id        FROM data WHERE deviceID = 32 AND inputID = 12
SELECT state     FROM data WHERE deviceID = 32 AND inputID = 12
SELECT onphrase  FROM data WHERE deviceID = 32 AND inputID = 12
SELECT offphrase FROM data WHERE deviceID = 32 AND inputID = 12
SELECT when      FROM data WHERE deviceID = 32 AND inputID = 12
```

## A quick improvement

A quick way to reduce the number of requests by a factor of 5 is by retrieving all the hash values you need in one request:

```
foreach (string h in RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.Hashes)
{
    var keys = await db.HashGetAsync(h, new RedisValue[]{ "id", "state", "onphrase", "offphrase", "when" })
    StateRedis state = new StateRedis
    {
        Id = keys[0],
        InputState = keys[1],
        OnPhrase = keys[2],
        OffPhrase = keys[3],
        When = keys[4],
    };

    returnedDevices.Add(state);
}
```

This code will make 1 request per hash, or 384 requests. This is still probably more requests than should be made for one operation, but may make the Redis implementation comparable to the SQL one.

## Possible better solutions

### Pipelining requests

Redis can respond to requests very quickly, but right now the code is waiting for the previous response before sending the next request. Instead, you can [pipeline the requests](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html): Send them all up front, then receive the responses.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StateRedis>> AllStatesAsync()
{
    List<StateRedis> returnedDevices = new List<StateRedis>();

    // Start every request without awaiting the responses
    List<Task<StateRedis>> stateTasks =
        RedisConnectionHelper.Instance.Hashes
        .Select(hashKey => GetStateRedisAsync(hashKey))
        .ToList();

    // Wait for the responses
    StateRedis[] states = await Task.WhenAll(stateTasks);
    return states;

    async Task<StateRedis> GetStateRedisAsync(RedisKey key)
    {
        var keys = await db.HashGetAsync(h, new RedisValue[]{ "id", "state", "onphrase", "offphrase", "when" })
        return new StateRedis
        {
            Id = keys[0],
            InputState = keys[1],
            OnPhrase = keys[2],
            OffPhrase = keys[3],
            When = keys[4],
        };
    }
}
```

### Store data as Redis strings

There are several ways you could speed this up further, but probably the best way would be to rethink how you're storing data in Redis. Right now you're storing this data in 384 hashes, so to get the data in all of them, you have to make multiple Redis requests because there is no command that will return data from multiple hashes.

Do you need these to be stored as hashes in Redis? I don't know what other data is stored in each hash, but if it makes sense, you could instead store this data as JSON-serialized Redis strings:

```
db.StringSet("device1:input1",   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new StateRedis { id = 1, state = "foobar", ... }))
db.StringSet("device1:input2",   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new StateRedis { id = 2, state = "foobar", ... }))
...
db.StringSet("device32:input12", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new StateRedis { id = 384, state = "foobar", ... }))
```

With this format, you can query all the strings at once:

```
var values = db.StringGet(new RedisKey[] { "device1:input1", "device1:input2", ... });
foreach (RedisValue value in values)
{
    var stateRedis = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StateRedis>(value);

    // stateRedis == new StateRedis { id = 1, state = "foobar", ... }
}
```

If the amount of data in each `deviceN:inputM` key is small, this may be acceptable. If you store a large binary object in each, then maybe you could store that blob in a *separate* string key named something like `deviceN:inputM:raw_data`.

### Combine hashes for each device/input

If it does make sense for your app to store the data in Redis hashes, then you could perhaps combine all the inputs for a device into a single hash:

```
db.HashSet("device1", new [] {
    new HashEntry("input1:id", 1),
    new HashEntry("input1:state", "foobar"),
    ...
    new HashEntry("input12:id", 12),
    new HashEntry("input12:state", "foobar"),
});
```

With this structure, you'd still need to make 32 requests to get the data for all devices, but if one of the items in the hash is a large binary blob, you would avoid transferring from Redis unnecessarily.

Comment: What an answer, I was not expecting that!  Well, I have just quickly tried your first suggestion, and I have got it down from `~200ms` to `~50ms`.  I'm still puzzled why its really slow (`~2500secs`) when communicating with Redis via our Linux server.  Anyway I'll assume it wont be an issue when the API in question will be running from the same server, as `localhost` Redis seems to be a lot quicker at the moment.  Yes, the hashes were an initial suggestion here, so they don't have to be.  I'll try pipelining next, then strings and see how I get on.

Comment: My guess is that it's latency. There's a method `db.Ping()` that will tell you how long it takes to receive a single response from Redis, which should be the overhead for each Redis request. This might help you troubleshoot: If the average latency is near 1ms, then the problem is likely the sheer number of requests. You could compare the latency from Redis with the latency from executing `SELECT 1` against SQL to see if Redis' overhead is comparable.

Comment: Thanks, I placed `db.Ping()` at the start of my method that gets a `hash` from the list and stores that hash, and I am getting `00:00:00.0029417` at the most, then it decreases the more `PUT` requests I do in Postman.  One thing I have noticed, is that the very first `GET`, `PUT`, etc. seems to be the slowest when I spin the app up, then the more requests I make the time goes down to a much lower number.  Mind you, I have just pinged my local Redis container, maybe I should point it at the one on the server to see the results.